# Why do I have to use Import-Module before accessing the registry

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I am writing a script in Powershell that configures a Windows server.
One of the tasks is setting up the IIS.
For that I import two modules in the beginning:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

Only after the import, I can access the registry under IIS:\ and make changes like so:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\'+$site_name -Name logfile.directory -Value "C:\logs\iis\"
```

Why is that?

I have a hard time understanding how the registry is structured.

Comment: You're not accessing the registry - the `IIS:` drive maps to the IIS configuration hierarchy, all of which is stored in XML files on disk. The underlying provider that facilitates this mapping is stored in the `WebAdministration` module, along with the default `IIS:` drive. In other words, the `IIS:` drive is not part of PowerShell itself, but of the module - which is why you need to import it

Comment: The `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet is very often used with working with the registry, because the Registry is presented in PowerShell with a `PSDrive`.  You can list all of the `PSDrive` objects on your system with the `Get-PSDrive` cmdlet.  Anything with a PSDrive can be interacted with using the `Get/Set-ItemProperty` cmdlets.  It seems we are migrating away from PSDrives though, as fewer and fewer modules present them these days.

Comment: Thank you guys so much it makes sense now !